# How to change order and width of two vertical regions in Drupal Bootstrap theme?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, themes, region

There are  three vertical regions in Drupal Bootstrap theme:
**Primary (narrow), Content (wide), Secondary (narrow)**

I need to move Content region  to the left:

**Content (wide), Primary (narrow),  Secondary (narrow)**
and change width of two regions: make Content  region wider (e.g. one column of grid  wider) and Primary region –  one column narrower , respectively.

How should it be done?

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap subtheme, you can override the

```
/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/theme/system/page.tpl.php
```

file, where the general layout is defined.

Regions are rendered in this file with (for the "Content" region) :

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

So basically, create a subtheme of bootstrap theme, then in the /templates folder of your subtheme, create a page.tpl.php file, copy the content of

```
/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/theme/system/page.tpl.php
```

and you can start modifying the layout, modify the markup, and move around the

```
<?php print render($page['region_machine_name']); ?>
```

...to get what you want.

The "region_machine_name" can be found in your .info file (theme root) :

```
regions[content] = 'Content'
```

In this file you'll find that sidebars are always 4 columns wide in bootstrap drupal theme :

```
<?php if (!empty($page['sidebar_first'])): ?>
  <aside class="col-sm-4" role="complementary">
    <?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>
  </aside>  <!-- /#sidebar-first -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Regions width are defined by bootstrap scaffolding classes ("col-sm-4", col-xs-3"...) in the same file (page.tpl.php) and in /sites/all/themes/bootstrap/theme/system/page.vars.php. In this file hooks are implemented (bootstrap_preprocess_page for instance), and scaffolding classes are "calculated" (if only one sidebar then...if two sidebar then...). You can implement these hooks in your subtheme's template.php and modify regions width by modifying these classes.

Here is a portion of the default bootstrap_preprocess_page() hook :

```
// Add information about the number of sidebars.
// 2 sidebars -> content is 6 columns wide
if (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first']) && !empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
  $variables['content_column_class'] = ' class="col-sm-6"';
}
// only one sidebar -> content is 9 columns wide
elseif (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first']) || !empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
  $variables['content_column_class'] = ' class="col-sm-9"';
}
// no sidebar : full width content (12 columns)
else {
  $variables['content_column_class'] = ' class="col-sm-12"';
}
```

So in fact to modify sidebars width, it's in your page.tpl.php (default : 4 columns). If you modify your sidebars widths, you must modify the content width too, and it's in template.php / your_subtheme_name_preprocess_page() : replace $variables['content_column_class'] by the right bootstrap class